# Prevent A Parent Action With Bootstrap Popover

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following JavaScript:

```
$( ".aa-list-menu-item-heading" ).click(
    function()
    {
        $( this ).find( ".aa-collapse" ).toggleClass( "glyphicon-chevron-left glyphicon-chevron-down" );
        $( this ).next( ".row" ).slideToggle();
    }
);

$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover();
```

The popover link is within a child div with class .aa-list-menu-item-heading

When I click the popover, it works, but the $( ".aa-list-menu-item-heading" ).click() runs

How can I prevent the parent child popover actioning the parent .click()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You "can't", but you could check if the target of your click is the popover in your DIV click event handler and skip the execution just in case.

```
$( ".aa-list-menu-item-heading" ).click(
    function(e)
    {
        if ($(e.target).data('toggle') !== 'popover'){
            $( this ).find( ".aa-collapse" ).toggleClass( "glyphicon-chevron-left glyphicon-chevron-down" );
            $( this ).next( ".row" ).slideToggle();
        }
    }
);
```